# Is alternative icon available for watchOS?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-3

Since iOS 10.3, developers can set [alternative icons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname) which is very nice.

Is it supported in the companion watchOS app?

My app was recently rejected due to this.

> Specifically, we noticed that for the user selected alternative icon themes no alternative Apple Watch icons matching the iPhone icon theme were submitted.

Comment: Regarding the app rejection "Your watchOS app icon should be visually similar to your iOS app icon to show users that they are connected." — https://developer.apple.com/watchos/submit/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have posted my answer, verified by my own experience of successfully submitted the app and released on June 29, 2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

watchOS does not support alternate icon, as of watchOS 4.0 beta.

I ended up answering Apple Review team, the app is intended to not provide alternate icons in Watch App.

Answer (score -3):

From Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/), you should provide all kinds of sizes for your alternate icon.

In your case, you should provide the icon of watchOS app's size.

> Like your primary app icon, each alternate app icon is delivered as a collection of related images that vary in size. When the user chooses an alternate icon, the appropriate sizes of that icon replace your primary app icon on the Home screen, in Spotlight, and elsewhere in the system. To ensure that alternate icons appear consistently throughout the system—the user shouldn't see one version of your icon on the Home screen and a completely different version in Settings, for example—provide them in the same sizes you provide for your primary app icon (with the exception of the large App Store icon). See [App Icon Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/#app-icon-sizes).

---

**How to:**

the value of `CFBundleIconFiles` in `info.plist` is an array. You should fill it with  the names of icon files:

- no @2x @3x suffix
- no force rules about file naming, app will automatically pick the right solution for the sense it needs.
- no care about order

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your reference is about iOS. watchOS does not support alternate icon.