# Xcode 14.2 Archiving the app fails with CoreData: error: API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, ab-testing

Archiving the app in Xcode 14.2 gives me the following error when the code does not use CoreData:

```
API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x600001a81b90, store PSC = 0x0)
```

I am attempting to add alternate app icons for an app that supports Watchos for A/B testing. Should the alternate app icons also be added for Watchos?

What I've already tried:

- I have reviewed the assets folders - no duplicate names

  I have tried cleaning Derived Data, clean builds and restarting the
  Mac.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is because of CoreData. can you just review your code once again whether there contains any type of CoreDataAPI.

and one more thing I think [Is alternative icon available for watchOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532717/is-alternative-icon-available-for-watchos) this question will help your more about your second question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by the app’s alternate icon configured with a single size, and its primary icon (1024x1024 png) with individual sizes

This issue got resolved after I changed my primary app icon to single size which helped to archive the app successfully